# Remove text before the second pattern using gsub in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm simply looking for a code using `gsub` in order to remove all text before the second pattern `"_"`

I used:

```
for (i in 1:length(df1)){
  df1[, i]<- gsub("_([^_]**)", "",df1[, i])
}
```

but it does not work; here is my data frame

```
query       cluster_000001                  cluster_000003
1: query    cluster_000001_Phycodnaviridae  cluster_000003_Baculoviridae
2: query    cluster_000001_Phycodnaviridae  cluster_000003_Baculoviridae
3: query    cluster_000001_Phycodnaviridae  cluster_000003_Baculoviridae
4: query    cluster_000001_Phycodnaviridae  cluster_000003_Baculoviridae
5: query    cluster_000001_Phycodnaviridae  cluster_000003_Baculoviridae
```

and what I should get :

```
query   cluster_000001  cluster_000003
1: query     Phycodnaviridae     Baculoviridae
2: query     Phycodnaviridae     Baculoviridae
3: query     Phycodnaviridae     Baculoviridae
4: query     Phycodnaviridae     Baculoviridae
5: query     Phycodnaviridae     Baculoviridae
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Try `df1[, (2:3) := lapply(.SD, sub, pattern = ".*_",  replacement = ""), .SDcols = 2:3]`

Comment: @akrun What if the is a subset of my real table I want to do it for each column in my real dataframe?

Comment: Then, change the `.SDcols` accordingly.  Here, I specified the column index 2, 3

Comment: @akrun something like that ? : `df1[, (1:length(df1)) := lapply(.SD, sub, pattern = ".*_", replacement = ""), .SDcols = 1:length(df1)]`

Comment: or `seq_along(df1)`

Comment: wouldn't it be a valid approach for you to split the string on the "_" (underscores) and then just keep the second one; if you don't manage to build the right regex and are in a hurry? to apply it to each column - wrap it in an apply function

Comment: PS: is it coinncidence or are you trying to replace the column names in you data?